# Paper on geometry of 2-level Quantum states influenced by noise

Tags: quantum-state, resource-request, noise, state-space-geometry

Are there papers discussing geometry of quantum states (especially two level systems) influenced by noise.

Comment: Two-level systems, Bloch sphere is enough? If so, Nielsen and Chuang's book, chap 8 is enough.

Comment: this is a bit vague. What kind of noise? What you mean precisely with "discussing geometry"? The kind of evolution a state goes through doesn't change the geometry of the underlying space of all states. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I found the answer in first comment. Thanks

Comment: @gIS I think the question is specific enough if the answer was simply the evolution of qubits on the Bloch sphere